# Actual argument Login cannot be converted to OnClickListener by method invocation conversion

Tags: android

I am experiencing this error when I try to compile my app in android studios. Error message is this:

```
Error:(32, 15) error: method setOnClickListener in class View cannot be applied to given types;
required: OnClickListener
found: Login
reason: actual argument Login cannot be converted to OnClickListener by method invocation conversion
```

This is my code:

```
package tryoutonly.com.contactform;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button bLogin;
    EditText etemail, etPassword;
    TextView jvRegisterLink;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemail);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        jvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jvRegisterLink);


        bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        jvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bLogin:
                break;

            case R.id.jvRegisterLink:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Apparently the error is shown in the code below

```
bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

well, the error is self-explaining, your class does not implements the OnClickListener interface.

Change your class declaration from

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity
```

to

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener
```

Comment: IF it has solved your question then accept it please ;)